# Prevent added user script from WKWebView to run on our website

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit

We have an iOS app which loads a route of our website into a `WKWebView`. It then uses `WKUserContentController` to add a script using `addUserScript`. This javascript-file will therefor run on our website every time the app opens the `WKWebView`. This was previously intended behavior.
However, we have now identified issues with this script which has caused us to want to perform all the actions on the server side. The injected javascript from the app does however interfere with our execution on our server javascript. Is there anyway, from our servers perspective, to prevent the added user script from running?

The added user script waits for `document.readyState == 'complete'` and then starts running.